# Rails module model autoload clash (ckeditor gem)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ckeditor

So, I have already asked this in Gem github, but no answer as of now.
I am trying to implement rails ckeditor gem into my application.

The problem is there is an Ckeditor::Asset model defined as part of the ckeditor gem, and in my application i have my own Asset model defined for purposes and needs related to my main application functionality.

So, there is a model/asset.rb file and models/ckeditor/asset.rb file, and the ckeditor one is causing me problems.

I am getting:
Unable to autoload constant Asset, expected .../app/models/ckeditor/asset.rb to define it

My question is, what is a workaround so I can actually use ckeditr and leave my asset model as is?

Thanks

----- ADDITIONAL INFORMATION DUE TO COMMENTS:

models/asset.rb:

```
class Asset < ApplicationRecord
...
end
```

models/ckeditor/asset.rb (auto generated with gems generator)

```
class Ckeditor::Asset < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Ckeditor::Orm::ActiveRecord::AssetBase

  delegate :url, :current_path, :content_type, to: :data

  validates :data, presence: true
end
```

Comment: You're not getting any answers because you haven't shown your files. Where did model/asset.rb come from and what does it contain? It's not from Ruby or Rails, so you must have devised it yourself. And why are you looking into the gem? Not necessary. I don't understand why these two files,  model/asset.rb and model/ckeditor/asset.rb, even exist. Please try again.

Comment: It is pretty straightforward and contents of the files is not really the matter of the question.

model/asset.rb is yes, my file, which is an Asset model I use for my purposes.

model/ckeditor/asset.rb file is needed by the CkEditor gem, so it is not my file but it is needed by the gem itself. Without it, gem is not working and is complaining that is should be defined.

It is simply a matter of autoloading i think.

Comment: Added files contents...

Comment: OK. My apologies. I use ckeditor but I don't use it to upload pictures, so my install does not have app/models/ckeditor files. I see the installer also generates a migration. Did you remember to do a rake db:migrate?

Comment: Yes, sure, migration was executed. Sorry from my side too, i was not clear i needed ckeditor for file uploads :).

Comment: This is what I would try next: copy the gem's asset.rb file to your local setup. If that does not break it, modify it one bit at a time until you have the features you want. I'm betting it's a matter of syntax only. Maybe even just a capital letter where it should be lowercase. Good luck!